# ASP selectable grid/table, programmatically generated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to populate some sort of grid/table programmatically and have it respond to user clicks.

I can populate an ASP table but it doesn't seem to have any OnClick or OnSelectionChanged events.

The ASP DataGrid seems to have to be data bound, but that's ok because I can programmatically build a DataTable and bind that. Except that I don't seem to be able to populate the cells in the table (though I can build rows and columns)

Also, I have built a GridView with 2 empty rows of 2 columns and a handler attached to its OnSelectedIndexChanged event but it never gets fired. Why not? Is it because the cells are empty?

I am new to all this ASP and Web coding in general so please forgive stupid questions!